# HBase cache vs external

Tags: caching, bigdata, hbase

Does in make sense to invest into additional in-memory cache for HBase data like GridGain or Redis or it's better to put more resources into HBase's cache?
We have read pattern approximately 50/50, access by key/scan queries.

Comment: I was under the impression that HBase has built a lot of hbase-specific logic into its LRU and bucket (off-heap) block cache implementations http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#block.cache, so I'd be surprised if a general purpose solution turns out to be more efficient.